# I am a Romanian married to a Dominican and we want to travel to Romania what visa does he need?

Tags: visas, romania

I am a Romanian citizen married to a Dominican citizen. We would like to travel to Romania but there is no embassy in the Dominican Republic. The embassy of Venezuela informed me that they don't deal with visas for Dominicans married to Romanians… and the embassy of Colombia never seem to answer the phone or any of the emails I sent. This is very frustrating as we are trying to find out something for two months now.

Comment: Do you mean [this embassy](http://mae.ro/romanian-missions/3176#889)? (It seems to be the right one but in English “embassy of Colombia” suggests the embassy representing the Republic of Colombia *in* the Dominican Republic so it might be useful to clarify the question.)

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Are you contacting an embassy of Venezuela?  Or Romanian Embassy in Venezuela?  And same for Colombia.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page, the [Romanian embassy in Colombia](http://www.mae.ro/en/romanian-missions#854) is indeed responsible for the consular services for Dominican Republic.

In addition, the following information found on the site of [Romanian ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2061) seems relevant for you:

> Long-stay visas for third-country nationals who are family members of Romanian nationals are issued by the Romanian diplomatic missions and consular posts free of charge.
>
> Entry-visas for third-country nationals, family members of EU and EEA citizens are issued free of charge.

If you can get a free long-stay multiple-entry visa for your husband, that seems like the best option for you.